# Stack Exchange Inbox Items Duplicated (And Then Some)

Tags: bug, email

So, I started getting all my Stack Exchange inbox items duplicated.

[image]

It started with this email, and every email since has done the same thing. Not 15 times, but several times.

Comment: Maybe it *really* wants you to comment on that question.

Comment: It's just the email, right? Your inbox on the site doesn't have duplicate notifications?

Comment: @AnnaLear DERP (regarding migration). Yes, that is correct. It's just the email.

Comment: I had this happen to me today also.  The email came with four copies of the same notification.

Comment: I haven't had this happen again.